# Why are nested divs (Bootstrap example) so common?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap is one of many sites where I have noticed this practice, that to me seems bad but it is widespread enough, and done by people more experienced than me that I think I must be missing something. Take for instance the 2.1.0 version of [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), if you view source, lines 44-46 (the top of page menu) are these:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
```

I understand the associated CSS properties of each class, and the shortcomings of using a framework that is made to be useful to as many people in as many situations as possible but having largely finished a design I am now trying to clean my markup. Is there a reason to use 3 divs when 2 would (from what I can tell) suffice?

While '.container' has a set width, clear properties, and margin settings for centering, I don't understand why '.navbar-inner' is in a separate div from it's parent. It seems like it would make more sense to add it as a class to it's parent div and reduce one layer of nesting.

Is there a reason why I should leave this structure in place (or for that matter something I  should incorporate into future coding practices)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you could reduce the complexity of the markup by combining several classes like

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inner container">
```

or

```html
<div class="navbar-inverse-fixed-top-inner-container">
```

But for that kind of markup to work, you would have to generate quite a lot of CSS rules to satisfy every case.

By separating most use-cases in CSS and with the markup, you end-up with something quite readable and not so heavy on both CSS and HTML sides.

This also allows you to satisfy lots of combinations for a lot of users.

---

IMHO, the main principle behind that hierarchy is **scalability**. Because you can easily remove the `.container` to put something else - or just move it elsewhere. This is only for later use, when you'll read your code again, in 10 years maybe.

Another principle I'd like to point out is **encapsulation**. If you program in object oriented languages (JS, C++, C#, Java, many others..) then you must be familiar with it.

Based on your example :

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
```

The `.container` should not be *aware* of its container - you seem to agree with that - but nor should the `.navbar-inner` be aware of its own `.navbar` state : whether it's fixed, inverse, or not even a navbar.

The `.navbar-inner` should only serve to provide its children the appropriate behavior, and I think that's why it's best to keep it separated, even if you could mix it with the navbar.

---

Maybe in some new versions, or just if you want to change the default behavior, there may be conflicts between the navbar and its inner.

Let's try to avoid that and keep the intended structure. It doesn't look so messy anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Nesting divs allows you to style and access them separatelly, which can come in handy. But of course it depends on your actual needs, and as you state, a lot can be accomplished just by using css without excess divs.

Answer (score 2):

Thats the way styling (in this case for example width/height, border, margin, padding) works best on different browsers (IE vs. the rest).